# Delphi VCL make element "transparent" to clicks

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Is it possible to make VCL element transparent to clicks like disabling hit test in FMX?

Comment: If the control is a `WinControl` writing a `WM_NCHITTEST` handler returning `HTTRANSPARENT` might do the trick. But I don't know if this works only on top level windows or all controls with a handle.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, it works also for child windows. That's how e.g. `TCustomTransparentControl` allows clicks through when its `InterceptMouse` property is set to False.

Comment: Disable the control if you don't mind the look, or if it doesn't change (e.g. panel).

Comment: For non-wincontrols, you can return `HTNOWHERE` to `CM_HITTEST`.

Answer (score 2):

Put two Memos on the Form, but Memo2 partially behind Memo1 to test. Then add this code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    procedure Memo2Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo2Exit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    OriginalProc:TWndMethod;
    procedure MyWindowProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OriginalProc:=Memo1.WindowProc;
  Memo1.WindowProc:=MyWindowProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyWindowProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  OriginalProc(Msg);
  if Msg.Msg = WM_NCHITTEST then Msg.Result:=HTTRANSPARENT;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Memo1.WindowProc:=OriginalProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo2Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo2.Color:=clRed;
end;

procedure TForm1.Memo2Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo2.Color:=clWhite;
end;

end.
```